# Does there exist a decreasing sequence $A_n$ of bounded open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A_n \downarrow [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a decreasing sequence $A_n$ of bounded open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A_n \downarrow [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$?

If I take $$A_n = \bigcup_{q \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}} (q - 1/n, q + 1/n)$$
then actually $A_n \downarrow [0,1]$, since for all $n \geq 1$ and all irrational $x$ in $[0,1]$ there exists a rational within $1/n$ of $x$.

Comment: A well known application of Baire category Theorem  says this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such sequence. Let $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q=\{q_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=A_n\setminus\{q_n\}$. Then $\{U_n\cap[0,1]:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable family of dense open subsets of $[0,1]$ with empty intersection, which is impossible, since $[0,1]$ is a Baire space..